# How can I increase my disk space when Ubuntu is installed alongside with Windows?

Tags: disk-management

Some time ago i reinstalled windows, formating and deleting every partition. I then made 3 partitions:

> One only for Windows OS (about 25GB)
>
> One for Ubuntu OS (about 25GB, if i remember corectly 10GB for swap
>   memory and 15GB as an ext4 partition) (not sure if it was that, hope I
>   am not wrong) and like 200GB for all the other stuff.

Recently I got a message that i am running out of disk space.

My question is: is there a way to resize the 200GB partition and add more space for the Ubuntu partition?

Comment: Run this in terminal `sudo fdisk -l` then edit your question with the output

Comment: 10GB for swap memory I thing is to many. if I'm not mistaken, you nead the same amount of swap as ram is.
From centos DOC's What is Swap Space? (http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-swap-what-is.html)

Answer (score 2):

The program `baobab`, installed by default, can be an helpful tool to see how much space is kept by the several stuff, and maybe delete unnecessary files or move them into another partition.

[image: baobab]

This could be used to free some space before you decide how to resize the partitions.
So, you have:

- 25GB Windows
- 25GB Ubuntu
- 10GB swap
- 15GB ext4
- 200GB ?

Is the 200GB partition in ext4? Do you use that partition only for Ubuntu? If yes, you could mount your `/home` there  and resize the 25GB system partition to 12-13GB.

For which use you made the 15GB partition? If there is no specific use, you could merge the 200GB and the 15GB a single partition

Then, with these operation you could obtain a `/home` partition of ~227-228GB

Comment: Does not answer the OP's question, but gives a workaround

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest to install [GParted](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/gparted), it's a great tool for working with partitions.

Then, in your setup, from start I see one small problem: your swap. As a guideline rule, your swap shouldn't be larger as 1.5 * your total RAM memory, but not larger then 4Gb. So, 4Gb is enough, you don't need that entire 10Gb. Then I also assume your 200Gb is NTFS and is shared by both windows and linux (win can't work with ext4). So you can also resize that storage area and reassign the space to your Ubuntu.

1) Boot the desktop CD and unmount all your hard drive partitions and swap (you can do this in gparted).

2) Delete any unwanted partitions -> apply changes.

3) Resize your partitions one at at time.

4) Fix your partition table (order) with fdisk

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sda
```

At the fdisk prompt type the following commands

```
# Extra functionality
x

# Fix partition order
f

# Write changes to disk
w

# Quit fdisk
q
```

Reboot and your partitions should look much better.
Of course, backup your data first.

Answer (score 0):

This document describes how to resize a Wubi virtual disk. There are two distinct techniques.

1. You have to boot from a live CD/USB. This won't work while running Wubi.
2. Backup the root.disk (not required, but a good idea)
3. Mount the NTFS partition that your root.disk is on (this example assumes it's `/dev/sda1` and the mountpoint is `/media/win` - adjust accordingly in the following instructions):

> sudo mkdir -p /media/win
>   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/win

1. Check the size of the root.disk (not required)

> du -h --apparent-size /media/win/ubuntu/disks/root.disk

1. Run fsck on the root.disk

> fsck -f /media/win/ubuntu/disks/root.disk

1. Resize - specify the desired final size (this example resizes to 10 GB)

> resize2fs /media/win/ubuntu/disks/root.disk 10G

1. Reboot back into Wubi Ubuntu

Source : [Resize Wubi Disk](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeWubiDisk)