# How to increase storage memory in my system(14.04)(installed alongside Windows 7)?

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, partitioning, windows-7, storage

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 7 by selecting 30GB approximately. Now I want to increase storage memory with out affecting both Ubuntu and Windows.

I saw this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112727/how-can-i-increase-my-disk-space-when-ubuntu-is-installed-alongside-with-windows), but I can't find solution in there.

When I do,

```
arul@ARUL-PC:~$ sudo fdisk -l
```

I got response,

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x283091b8

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048   102606847    51302400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2   *   102606848   307199999   102296576    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       307204094   625139711   158967809    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       307204096   389933567    41364736    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       449028096   512002047    31486976    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       512006144   625139711    56566784    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda8       389935104   443273215    26669056   83  Linux
/dev/sda9       443275264   449015807     2870272   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Please provide some solutions.

Comment: To which partition do you want to add space, Windows or Ubuntu?

Comment: @Pabi need to add space in Ubuntu(sda8)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows go to the Disk Management Utility and shrink the disk.
Then boot either a live [gparted](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) or a live Ubuntu and start gparted.
You can then add the unallocated space to the Ubuntu partition.

Comment: I am not well in partitioning, but I can't extend available free space in windows disk management.

Comment: I would also recommend using gparted as well. You will need to be careful with expanding because it can distort your data. Elastic partitions are good for expanding

Comment: In the Disk Management Utility you need to right click on the disc and select Shrink Volume. You can find a tutorial [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309169.aspx)

Comment: @ryekayo I would not recomend resizing ntfs with gparted, just use the builtin Windows tool.

Comment: Why would that be if you dont mind me asking? Im still kind of novice to some of this stuff. I have partitioned to NTFS before using gparted...

Comment: With the wrong settings in gparted the resizing can cause boot problems, it is saver with the Windows tool. See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoResizeWindowsPartitions)

Comment: @Pabi I have shrink some memory from other disk, can you give more detail about using gparted because If I do anything wrong may my data will loss....

Comment: @ryekayo can you please explain what are the risk factors should I have to consider?

Comment: In gparted select your Ubuntu partition and click resize/move. Then just expand the partition.

Comment: The risk factor is that your cutting into Ubuntu's partition. If you resize that, you have to risk losing/corrupting data.